# Using Google Drive Document OCR from Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, ionic-framework, google-drive-api

I would like to build an app using Ionic/Parse that allows me to take a picture with a mobile device camera, and do text processing of the image. From what I gather open source libraries are a little finicky, so for the purposes of prototyping I was hoping to use Google Drive's OCR capabilities.

The user would take a picture of a document, and my Cloud Code would send the picture to google drive, perform the ocr, and on ocr success, the picture would be sent back to my Parse db.

I am looking for some wisdom on this approach...Is this realistic or am I just totally off my rocker? Is there perhaps a service that integrates the two things? Am I just going to waste the same amount of time getting this to work as I would trying to integrate an open source OCR library? From an implementation prospective, would I run into authentication/data format/whathaveyou issues?

Hoping for some, been there tried that, these are some useful lessons..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I run this service.

Approach seems reasonable. http://ocrestful.com does exactly what you're describing, via an all-REST API. Permanently free tier available.